# Split new line after certain character

Tags: php

Hello i try to make this

I have variable with this

```
  $var = 'text;text2;text3';
```

I want after ; to split on new line with foreach i want to make something like this

```
$var = 'text1;text2;text3';
// here is splitter or anything i dont know

foreach($var as $i) {
echo $i;
}
```

Output will be

```
 text1
 text2
 text3
```

Comment: https://eval.in/948551

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to do this:

```
$var = 'text;text2;text3';
$cmds = explode(';', $var) ;
foreach ($cmds as $cmd) {
    // echo $cmd ; // do something with $cmd
    $rcon->sendCommand($cmd) ;
}
```

Comment: But i cant specify <br> html tag because i use it here
`code`
foreach ($vars as $var) {
$rcon->sendCommand($var);
}
`code`

Comment: But now it display it like this

```text1 text2 text3```

Comment: @LubomirStankov That's what you want ?

Comment: i want this for every line ```$rcon->sendCommand('text1`);``` ```$rcon->sendCommand('text2`);```